# Pass data to middleware

Tags: django, django-middleware

I have middleware which do some work for me. Is it possible to pass some data to this middleware in respect to template which will be rendered?

Lets assume that I have urls:

```
url(r'^some/$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'some.html'}, name='community', kwargs={'value': 'value'}),
```

and I would like to pass value to middleware. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can look at view kwargs in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/middleware/#process-view